# PHP Export to CSV is putting all in 1 column

Tags: php, csv

First a disclaimer, I am a noob here. I am trying to output my results into an excel file, however for some reason I can't seem to figure it, all the results are entering into the same column

Here is the function that I am using to convert it to the file:

```
function createCSVFile($filename,$headings,$data) {
    // Set Output Headers
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.csv");
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    $head = array();
    foreach ($headings as $heading) {
      $head[] = $heading;
    }

    fputcsv($fp, $head);
    $rowData = array();
    // Put the data into the csv
    foreach ($data as $row) {

        foreach ($row as $item) {
            $rowData[] = $item;
        }
        fputcsv($fp, $rowData);
        unset($rowData);
    }
}
```

Here is some sample data and the structure of what I am passing:

## $filename

```
$filename = "Staff-list";
```

## $headings

```
$headings = array("Username","First Name","Last Name","Start Date", "End Date");
```

## $data

```
$data = getStaffDetails();
```

Which returns:

```
array(6) {
[0]=>
  array(5) {
        [0]=>
    string(12) "James21"
        [1]=>
    string(3) "James"
        [2]=>
    string(9) "Michael"
        [3]=>
    string(10) "2016-06-01"
        [4]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
        [0]=>
    string(14) "thombommom"
        [1]=>
    string(5) "Thomas"
        [2]=>
    string(7) "Bomarius"
        [3]=>
    string(10) "2016-12-01"
        [4]=>
    string(10) "0000-00-00"
  }
}
```

And here is what it looks like in the ouput:
[image]

## Update 1:

As per Marks solution below, I tried setting the deliminator in the PHP func to **;** like so:

```
 fputcsv($fp, $head,';');
```

However, now the output just has semi colons instead of commas
[image]

Comment: MS Excel won't always recognise a `,` as a separator; depending on your locale settings, you may need to use `;` instead... this is why MS Excel is not good when reading CSV files

Comment: Either you set `,` as a seperator when you are importing in excel or you change your seperator in the php script to `;`

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for the quick reply. I tried that by setting the deliminator in the fputcsv function however, instead of commas in the above image, it now has ';' :/ any thoughts?

Comment: I've tried your code and it seems to work fine. Maybe there is a problem with settings of Excel (or other program which is used to open csv file)?

Comment: CSV is not a good format to use with MS Excel for precisely this reason; One option is to write a first line in the file telling MS Excel what separator to expect (e.g. `sep=;`), but this will not work with all versions of MS Excel or with other csv readers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the reasons I hate windows so much is that with every version, something is different making it harder for devs. Argh.... Anyway, what you need to do is  override system setting ("list separator character") with: **'sep=;'**.

The first thing you should pass to **fputcsv** is:

```
$seperator = "sep=;";
fputcsv($fp, $seperator, ';', ' ');
```

Then Make your data an array of arrays with the first array being your headings like so:

```
$data = array(array("One","Two", "Three"), array('1','2','3'),array('1','2','3'),array('1','2','3'));
```

Just because you said you're a noob I'll give ya the whole function:

```
function createCSVFile($filename,$data) {
    // Set Output Headers
    header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}.csv");
    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // This will override system setting ("list separator character") and Excel will open the file correctly.
    $seperator = "sep=;";
    fputcsv($fp, $seperator, ';', ' ');

    // Get the array initialised.
    $rowData = array();

    // put the data into the csv
    foreach ($data as $row) {

        foreach ($row as $item) {
            $rowData[] = $item;
        }
        fputcsv($fp, $rowData);
        unset($rowData);
    }
}
```

Keep me posted!

Comment: It returns error, so $separator must be like: $separator = ["sep=;"]; Otherwise PHP will return error stating that fputcsv second parameter must be array and string given.